# Detect if BasicBlock is in a Loop

Tags: llvm, static-analysis

I am a beginner in LLVM and I am trying to write an LLVM pass. My pass is pretty simple: it detects Loops and function calls. I want to know if the function call is in a loop and detect sub-loops.

The problem I have is that my pass prints the function calls twice when the call is in a loop. This is my code :

```
void BlocksInLoop(Loop *L,unsigned nlvl){
  errs() <<"Loop level"<< nlvl << " {\n";
  BasicBlock* h = L->getHeader();
  ScalarEvolution *SE = &getAnalysis<ScalarEvolutionWrapperPass().getSE();
  errs() <<"Loop trip count :"<< SE->getSmallConstantTripCount(L) << "\n";
  std::vector<Loop*> subLoops = L-> getSubLoops();
  Loop::iterator j,f; 
  for (j = subLoops.begin(), f = subLoops.end();j!=f ; ++j)
    BlocksInLoop(*j ,nlvl+1);
  unsigned numBlocks = 0;
  Loop::block_iterator bb;
  for(bb = L-> block_begin(); bb != L-> block_end();++bb){
    BasicBlock* BB = *bb;
    for(BasicBlock::iterator i = BB->begin() , e = BB->end(); i!=e; ++i){
      if(isa<CallInst>(&(*i)) || isa<InvokeInst>(&(*i))){
        errs()<<"Call "<< cast<CallInst((*i))->getCalledFunction()->getName() << "\n"; 
        }
     }
  }
  errs()<< "}\n";
  } 

  virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F){
    LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>().getLoopInfo();
    errs() << "Function " << F.getName () + "{\n";
    for( Function::iterator b = F.begin() , be = F.end() ;b != be; ++b){
      for(BasicBlock::iterator i = b->begin() , ie = b->end();i != ie; i ++){
        if(isa<CallInst>(&(*i)) || isa<InvokeInst>(&(*i))){
          errs()<<"Call "<< cast<CallInst>(&(*i))->getCalledFunction()->getName() << "\n"; 
        }
      }
    }
    for(LoopInfo::iterator i = LI.begin(), e = LI.end(); i!=e; ++i)
      BlocksInLoop (*i,0);
    errs()<< "}\n\n"; 
    return(false);
  }
```

If the input is for example :

```
void foo(){
for(int i=0; i++; i<10)
  foo();
}
```

This is the output that I get :

```
Function foo{
Call foo
Loop level0 {
Loop trip count :0
Call foo
}
}
```

So I m looking for a way to be able to detect if the Call is in a loop and if so ignore the first print. Is it possible and if so how? (The trip count is also wrong and always 0 but I ll try to fix that later.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of achieving your objective, skip those basic block that belongs to a loop.

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F){
LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>().getLoopInfo();

for(LoopInfo::iterator i = LI.begin(), e = LI.end(); i!=e; ++i)
  BlocksInLoop (*i,0);

errs() << "Function " << F.getName () + "{\n";
for( Function::iterator b = F.begin() , be = F.end() ;b != be; ++b){
  for(LoopInfo::iterator L = LI.begin(), e = LI.end(); L!=e; ++L) {
    if(L->contains(&*b)){
      break; // Skip those BB that belong to a loop.
    }       
  }  
  for(BasicBlock::iterator i = b->begin() , ie = b->end();i != ie; i ++){
    if(isa<CallInst>(&(*i)) || isa<InvokeInst>(&(*i))){
        errs()<<"Call "<< cast<CallInst>(&(*i))->getCalledFunction()->getName() << "\n"; 
    }
  }
}
return(false);
```

}

Note: I haven't run this code, it may have syntax issues, but this is the overall idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I found another solution. I wont test it but I´ll validate it because I guess it is another smart way to do it and I feel ashamed I didnt think about it.